Suggestions for good workflows with git, when gerrit is the central repo
I have some major overhead when working with Gerrit. I have not found any guides that makes sense to me, on how to adopt a local workflow for Gerrit. What follows is how I work locally when the central repo is run by Gerrit. I would like to improve this.

I do dev-branches in any way I like. This usually means sub-branches, and ALOT of commits. Many of them with commit messages like "WIP" or "tmp". This is for my eyes only.

Make certain to git rebase master

If the name of the final dev-branch is called "dev-branch", then I create a new branch from that called "dev-branch-cl".

I squash "dev-branch-cl" using git rebase so that all the history of my local development is thrown away without any way of retreiving it again (!!). Thats how i get to be exactly 1 commit away from master. e.g. by:
git rebase master -i

Then I push to gerrit as git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main%wip, and I do not forget the "%wip" tag on this push, so that it is not automatically set-up for review.

I commonly get messages back from gerrit on things i need to change before it accepts the CL. I make these modifications on the cl branch. On the CL branch, I keep no history, so after any change I do a git commit --ammend -a command. Always 1 commit away from master...

After I manage to get Gerrit to accept my CL, I switch back to the originial dev branch, and I pull over the changes from the cl branch
git checkout dev-branch
git restore --source=dev-branch-cl .


This last git restore command brings the changes over from the cl branch, and puts in my working tree. It only does so from the path specified ".", so one has to make certain one is in the root of the repo when calling this.

To make certain I have a zero diff, I call:
git difftool dev-branch-cl

with the changes from the cl branch added, I do:
git commit -a


If it turned out that I made no changes to accomade Gerrit, this will be with a --amend instead. In the message, I say it is is patchset 1, and I put the link to the gerrit review in this commit. One can use git tags too, if that is how you like it.

I look through the content in Gerrit at this point. This part is usually org-dependent due to different CI/CD pipelines etc. I do what I can to make it seem sane in Gerrit. Then I select in the interface to promote the CL from WIP to proper, and invite reviewers if this is needed. As the review progress, I keep developing in my dev-branch to accomodate/modify the feature. I keep every commit in my dev-branch logical, and keep track of the comments made in the review that they address.

When I feel I have addressed all comments, i switch over to my cl-branch, and bring all changes over:
git checkout dev-branch-cl
git restore --source=dev-branch .

I check that I have zero diff and that all files are tracked with the cl branch:
git difftool dev-branch
git status

then I push a new patchset:
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/main


I then switch back to my dev-branch, and make a commit indicating it to be the next patchset, and repeat until review is done in gerrit, and the CL is merged.
When the CL is merged, i leave my dev-branch intact on my local computer. While I do not develope on it again, there might be some paths I explored in the work for this feature, that I ended up discarding for the final merge... however, that work might be useful for me later, on a different feature development.
I wish this was not so overly complex. Would be great if i could just sit in dev-branch and have all these tasks abstracted away by some intelligent interface

Regarding the loss of commit history after a squash or amend, the history is not actually thrown away, it just becomes not readily reachable by the tip of your local branches. Those "lost" commits can be referenced again with git reflog.
Patch-sets also provide a sort of "commit history" as they are essentially the commits (refs) that accumulate as your change-set reaches merge-ability.
For a sane workflow, I lean on bash and Git aliases. Some core actions:
alias gfresh='git fetch && git checkout master && git reset --hard origin/master'
alias gmend='git add . && git commit --amend --reuse-message=HEAD'
alias grom='git fetch && git rebase origin/master'
alias gpomd='git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master%wip'
alias gpom='git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master'

For making small fast changes, just work straight off master:
gfresh
edit . # make changes
git add .
git commit # initial commit
edit .
gmend # amend as you work
gpom # create the change-set
gfresh # restore your local master branch

For more significant work, you can optionally create a local branch which needs to stay in sync with the tip of your change-set (the latest patch-set):
gfresh
git checkout -b new-work
edit .
git add .
git commit
gpomd # create change-set
grom # stay up-to-date
edit . # make more changes, code-review, etc
gmend && gpom # keep pushing patch-sets until ready to merge

After a while of this I found myself rarely using branches, especially pre-review (in draft), and just working off an up-to-date master and pushing up patch-sets (even if they were WIP) to a draft change-set when I needed to work on other changes. Basically, the draft change-set becomes your working branch.
Try to embrace the amend/squash workflow...it's similar to how a GitHub PR is often squashed and merged into a single commit during merge, leading to a more useful, navigable, and bisect-able history. In the off-chance you need to revisit a "lost" commit, you can always use the reflog (git reflog | grep commit).
Also worth mentioning is git-review which is a command-line tool which also cuts down the rigamarole.

Thanks. "Rarely using branches" is to me giving up on the benefits of Git for my own work. If I let Gerrit CLs with their patchsets be the stand-in for branches then I have a centralized system of version control like old SubVersion. I get the benefits of Gerrit, and the need to amend/squash, but why would I let this workflow influence my own work on my machine? I want work that I do to be in branches on my own computer, not a central server. I want them to be in proper branches so I get the history of what I have done. Not disconnected CLs whose history is only evident in a web-based gui.

This sounds very complex indeed. Sounds like you're trying to work against Gerrit?

This usually means sub-branches, and ALOT of commits. Many of them with commit messages like "WIP" or "tmp"

This sounds like a guide on how not to use Gerrit. Why have commits with pointless messages? Just amend the commit you're on?
The point of Gerrit is not to always be 1 commit away from main, but for each commit to be meaningful, "WIP" and "tmp" are not.
If you find youself multiple meaningful commits "away" from main, and you want each one to be reviewed individually, then Gerrit will create a chain of changes for the user to easily review.

I commonly get messages back from gerrit on things i need to change before it accepts the CL.

Unsure what you mean here? Like what?

As the review progress, I keep developing in my dev-branch to accomodate/modify the feature.

Sounds like you're creating new commits locally to then squash them before pushing them. Why? Just keep amending the commit you're working on and upload it? Why care so much of intermediary state of a commit?

While I do not develope on it again, there might be some paths I explored in the work for this feature, that I ended up discarding for the final merge

If there are some specific commits that you want to keep for future reference, you could always push them on top of your current work, and it would show up as a separate change that can they sit there forever. You can mark it private if you don't want others to see it.

Overall I feel like you're trying to work like you're using a PR workflow, when you're not, which is a common issue amongst new Gerrit users.
For this reason I've created a medium blogpost if you care to see how I use it.
Overall I think you're question is probably better answered on the Gerrit Mailing list, where it's easier to reply to the multiple points you raise. The Gerrit community doesn't really monitor stack overflow.
However, I want to thank you for your question as I feel like many new Gerrit users have the same problem and I hope this can be a place for people to learn.
